# How to move mesh not by center but by vertice

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I am using ThreeJS library in my project. I am setting a position of my mesh with : `mesh.position.set(x,y,z)` but I would like to move my mesh to x,y,z position by vertice. For example, move vertice 5 of the cube to 100,100,100 and the whole cube will move to that position, but not the center, but vertice. No displecement, just moving the mesh to point. How can this be done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load, or create, your geometry, you need to translate the geometry so that the desired vertex `v` has coordinate `( 0, 0, 0 )`.

```
geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation( - v.x, - v.y, - v.z ) );
```

Now, when you set the position

```
mesh.position.set( x, y, z )
```

the mesh will be translated so that the vertex of interest is located at the point `( x, y, z )`.

three.js r.68

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Figured it out ! ;)